# When n or p reaches ∞, what is the $\frac{n-p}{(n-1)p}$?

Tags: limits

Please tell me when n or p reaches ∞, what is the $\frac{n-p}{(n-1)p}$?

Because I need the result to check whether $T^2$, which the modified Hotelling’s statistics $T^2* \frac{n-p}{(n-1)p}$~F,

will be approximated as an average of p independent F statistics or not.

Thank you for your any help.

Comment: Can we assume that the other variable is fixed ?

Comment: Yes, that are two different conditions, one is when n → ∞, the other is when p → ∞.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\frac{n-p}{(n-1)p}=\frac{n-p}{np-p}=\frac{1-\frac{p}{n}}{p-\frac{p}{n}}$$

Hence the limit for $n\rightarrow \infty$ is $\frac{1}{p}$. Analogue you can get the other limit, which I leave as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Is when p → ∞, then it is (-1/(n-1))?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct result.